# dtrace errors when running opensnoop in El Capitan

Tags: macos, sip, dtrace

In order to diagnose slow terminal interaction (which turned out to be an unrelated problem), I ran `sudo opensnoop` and saw output like this: [dtrace errors](https://gist.github.com/nmk/64ad901d7d237a7be925)

I assume this has to do with SIP in El Capitan. Is it something to worry about? How can I dig deeper to understand what the probe IDs correspond to and what processes are causing the errors? What is the action #?

Answer (score 2):

You can white list portions of the restrictions when you boot to recovery HD and open terminal from the utilities window:

```
csrutil disable
csrutil enable --without dtrace
```

I haven't found good [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) on this, but Rich Trouton has done a magnificent job documenting the internals of SIP on his blog and public speaking engagements:

- https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/#more-7252
- http://www.jamfsoftware.com/resources/os-x-security-defense-in-depth/